# IPv6 addresses in dnsmasq

Tags: dns, ipv6, dnsmasq

As I need to use dnsmasq to route all requests on *.local to my local machine (and use there an IPv6 addresses), i set up the dnsmasq like this:

/etc/dnsmasq.d/my-local.conf

```
address=/local/::1
listen-address=::1
```

/etc/resolv.conf

```
nameserver ::1
nameserver 127.0.0.1
# Generated by NetworkManager
nameserver 192.168.43.1
```

But dig anything.local **returns no answer.** What did I set wrong?

```
radek@me:/$ dig anything.local

; <<>> DiG 9.8.1 <<>> anything.local
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 30189
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;anything.local.            IN  A

;; Query time: 0 msec
;; SERVER: ::1#53(::1)
;; WHEN: Sun Jan  8 09:39:10 2012
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 32
```

If change my-local.conf like this:

```
address=/local/127.0.0.1
listen-address=127.0.0.1
```

i get this:

```
radek@me:/$ dig anything.local

; <<>> DiG 9.8.1 <<>> anything.local
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 13675
;; flags: qr aa rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;anything.local.            IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
anything.local.     0   IN  A   127.0.0.1

;; Query time: 0 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.1#53(127.0.0.1)
;; WHEN: Sun Jan  8 09:40:47 2012
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 48
```

which means that troubles could be caused by IPv6 addresses.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it will work if you ask properly, that is: `dig aaaa anything.local`